# Custom Media Queries in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've an issue with Material UI Media Queries, how can I use custom Media Queries with Material UI
Currently I'm using brakepoints which already has a dimensions, which quietly not meeting my requirements

```
const match   = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
```

And Markup is

```
 {match ? 
     <React.Fragment>
         <Adapting
             anchorEl      = {anchorEl}
             isActive      = {isActive}
             openDrawer    = {openDrawer}
             setOpenDrawer = {setOpenDrawer}
         />
         
     </React.Fragment>
 : qtabs}
```

Comment: And what are your requirements?

Comment: [You're supposed](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) to pass media query string rather than breakpoints to `useMediaQuery()` hook for such cases.

Comment: The point was rather *'media query strings passed as parameter allow fine tuning with smaller granularity'*

Comment: Oh, I see. I did not get that from the question.

Comment: My requirements is basically simple, I would like to control each device width, from 360px x 640px and above, Material UI does not provides exact dimensions, it provides, a range of dimensions which is used commonly

Comment: as Yevgen stated `useMediaQuery()` takes a CSS media query string, `theme.breakpoints.down('md')` creates a media query string based on the breakpoint you have provided. You can just manual create your own media query strings to use in `useMediaQuery()` or `makeStyles()`. If you can make it work with different values for the breakpoints you could also override the breakpoint values in the theme. Material UI has a section about overriding [breakpoint values](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints)